# Parametrization of two surfaces $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ and $\frac{x^2}{p}+\frac{y^2}{q}=2z$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Can someone please help me to parametrize the following surfaces in terms of  hyperbolic(for second it might not be possible but i need some more convenient set of parametric equation than mine ) and trigonometric functions

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1 $$ and  $$\frac{x^2}{p}+\frac{y^2}{q}=2z$$
I have tried to do but the set of parametric equations I got were too complicated as I have to use those in some further calculation which makes the result very ugly. 
For first equation the set of parametric equations is: $$x=a\sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{c^2}}\cos v, \ \ y=b\sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{c^2}}\sin v \ \ z=u$$

and for second: $$x=\sqrt{2pu} \cos v ,\ \ y=\sqrt{2qu} \sin v, \ \ z=u $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$
> \frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1
> $$

Try

\begin{align}
x &=& a\cosh u \\
y &=& b\sinh u \cos v \\ 
z &=& c\sinh u \sin v
\end{align}

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{z^2}{c^2} &=& \cosh^2 u -(\sinh^2u\cos^2v + \sinh^2u\sin^2v) \\
&=& \cosh^2 u - \sinh^2 u \\
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray}

> $$
> \frac{x^2}{p} + \frac{\color{red}{y}^2}{q} = 2z
> $$

Try

\begin{align}
x &=& \sqrt{2up}\cos v \\
y &=& \sqrt{2uq}\sin v \\ 
z &=& u
\end{align}

In this case

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{x^2}{p} + \frac{y^2}{q} &=& \frac{2 u p}{p}\cos^2v + \frac{2 u q}{q}\sin^2 u = 2u \\
&=& 2z 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: In denominator of second equation it is $p \ and\  q$ instead of $p^2\ and \ q^2$

Comment: Can you please tell me how you get to this result ?

Comment: @hitman My apologies, I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

For the first: $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}\color{red}{-}\left(\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)=1$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&x&=a\cosh\theta,\\
&y&=b\cos\phi\sinh\theta,\\
&z&=c\sin\phi\sinh\theta.\\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Can you please tell me how you get to this result ?

Comment: I wrote those parenthesis to separate factors $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}$ and $\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{c^2}$. Minus between them tell us to compare with $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$.

Comment: Can you suggest anything about the second equation?

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ positive. This will change the equation. Write $\dfrac{x^2}{2zp}+\dfrac{y^2}{2zq}=1$ and think about $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ where $pq>0$ and $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$ where $pq<0$.

Comment: I dont know. there is no further info about it in the question. I have to compute the principal curvature of that curve.... that is why I need parametric equation